# Moment JS function `moment()` returning a different date/time on different devices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, datetime, momentjs

In my React Native app, I'm calculating the difference between a given time and the current time using `moment JS`. My code to calculate `minsLeft`, the difference between the two times, is:

```
let minsLeft = moment.duration(moment(request.AcceptedDate, "DD-MMM-YYYY h:mm:ss A")
      .subtract(new Date().getTimezoneOffset(), 'minutes')
      .add(request.ETA, 'minutes')
      .diff(moment())
)
```

`request.AcceptedDate` was `3-May-2020 04:37:31 PM`, and on that day (May 3) at 5pm I was getting a result of 23 minutes, as expected. On some devices though, I was getting values of negative several thousand minutes. The numbers were consistent with the app calculating the current date as `05/03/2021` instead of `03/05/2021`, as if the `moment()` function returns something different on different devices.

Has anyone run into anything like this and know where this discrepancy might be coming from?

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem. Turns out the moment() function depends on the timezone, date, and time set on the device. As you change your time or date or timezone, you get different results.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you found?

Answer (score 1):

```
var now  = "04/05/2021 11:00:00"; //new Date();
var then = "03/05/2021 11:20:00";

var s = moment.utc(moment(now,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"))).format("HH:mm:ss");
console.log("s:", s); 
//output: 23:40:00
```

Get difference between two times using moment. Hope it is works for react native. i tried it in react.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with timezones and formatting.

Considering your request to be:

> let request = {AcceptedDate: '06-May-2021 11:03:28 AM', ETA:60}

As per your comment **AcceptedDate** is of the format `DD-MMM-YYYY h:mm:ss A` and is already in UTC time.

Here are 2 different approaches to solve your issue:

**Approach 1:** Using *new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*

```
let minsLeft =  Math.abs(moment(request_TimeStamp.AcceptedDate).subtract(new Date().getTimezoneOffset(), 'minutes').add(request_TimeStamp.ETA, 'minutes').diff(moment(), 'minutes'))
```

**Approach 2:** Using *moment().local()*

```
let minsLeft = Math.abs(moment(request_TimeStamp.AcceptedDate).utc(request_TimeStamp.AcceptedDate).local().add(request_TimeStamp.ETA, 'minutes').diff(moment(), 'minutes'))
```

I have created a [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@gavindmello97/time-diff-moments) with both the above approaches
[image: Snack Output]

**Kindly Vote and Flag my solution if it helped you in any way.** *Cheers!*

Comment: @manjish Check my solution. Its well tested! Also find the Snack where the entire implementation exists

Comment: Hi Gavin, thanks for your reply. AcceptedDate is of the form "DD-MMM-YYYY h:mm:ss A", so like 3-May-2020 04:37:31 PM. And it's actually already in UTC time, so the reason I'm subtracting the timezoneOffset is to get it back to the user's local time. I understand the code you've included, but I don't understand what the problem might be with my original code that this fixes. I think the only differences between your code and mine and that you do `.utc()` where I do `getTimezoneOffset`, and that you do `Math.abs` where I do `asMinutes()`. These all give the same result. Any further insight?

Comment: UPDATE: Hey @gkeenley, I have update my solution as per your comment "AcceptedDate is of the form "DD-MMM-YYYY h:mm:ss A", so like 3-May-2020 04:37:31 PM. And it's actually already in UTC time". I have tested my update solution and also updated the image and the snack in the above answer. Have a look and +1 vote my answer. Let me know if you need anything else. Happy to help!

Comment: If my solution has answered your question correctly, kindly mark my solution as the Answer.....

Comment: I've upvoted, and I'll accept once I've confirmed that this resolves my issue. The two calculations give me the same output as my existing code. What I want to know is whether there's something in my code that might give a different output on a different device, and if so, whether your code avoids that issue and is consistent between devices.

Comment: Sure @gkeenley test it out and let me know if my code gives a wrong output. I will do the necessary fixes